# Stuck on python text based game

Tags: python

I am creating a text based game for my Intro to Scripting class and I can't figure out how to fix my code! I am new to coding so this is all brand new to me, but I have managed to get this far. The rpoblem I am having is I want my code to stop the game if all 6 items are collected no matter which room the player is in or if the player enters the Sorcerer's Lair and has not collected all 6 items. But as it stands now my game is ending as soon as it begins and displays the message as if they have already collected all items and won the game. Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong???

```
# Initialize a variable to keep track of the number of collected items
collected_items = 0

# Game loop
while True:
    # Code to play the game and collect items

    # Increment the number of collected items
    collected_items += 1

    # Check if all 6 items have been collected
    if collected_items == 6:
        # Notify the player and end the game
        print("Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the Wicked Sorcerer!")
        break

# Define a dictionary to represent the layout of the rooms and their connections
rooms = {
    'Entrance Hall': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Secret Passageway', 'East': 'Throne Room', 'West': 'Grand Hall'},
    'Kitchen': {'South': 'Entrance Hall', 'East': 'Dining Room'},
    'Throne Room': {'West': 'Entrance Hall', 'North': 'Armory'},
    'Armory': {'South': 'Throne Room'},
    'Grand Hall': {'East': 'Entrance Hall'},
    'Dining Room': {'West': 'Kitchen'},
    'Secret Passageway': {'North': 'Entrance Hall', 'East': "Sorcerer's Lair"},
    "Sorcerer's Lair": {'West': 'Secret Passageway'}
}

# Define a dictionary to represent the items in each room
items = {
    'Grand Hall': 'Golden Chalice',
    'Throne Room': 'Silver Scepter',
    'Armory': 'Emerald Necklace',
    'Kitchen': 'Diamond Crown',
    'Dining Room': 'Enchanted Orb',
    'Secret Passageway': 'Mystic Amulet'
}


# Define a function to display the player's status
def display_status(current_room, inventory):
    print("Current Room:", current_room)
    print("Inventory:", inventory)
    if current_room in items:
        print("Item in Room:", items[current_room])


# Define the main function for gameplay
def main():
    print("Welcome to The Lost Kingdom Text Adventure Game")
    print("Collect all 6 items to defeat the Wicked Sorcerer and win the game, or endure the Wicked Sorcerer’s Spell "
          "of Death")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
    print("************************************")  # Print line of asterisks

    current_room = 'Entrance Hall'
    inventory = []

    while True:
        display_status(current_room, inventory)
        print("************************************")  # Print line of asterisks
        command = input("Enter your command: ")

        if command.startswith("go"):
            direction = command.split()[1]
            if direction in rooms[current_room]:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
            else:
                print("Invalid direction!")

        elif command.startswith("get"):
            item = ' '.join(command.split()[1:])  # Collect item name even if it has multiple words
            if current_room in items and items[current_room] == item:
                inventory.append(item)
                del items[current_room]  # Remove item from room once picked up
                print("Item collected:", item)
            else:
                print("Item not available in this room!")

        else:
            print("Invalid command!")

        if len(items) == 0 and current_room == "Sorcerer's Lair":
            print("Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the Wicked Sorcerer!")
            break
        elif current_room == "Sorcerer's Lair":
            print("The Wicked Sorcerer cast the Spell of Death on you!...GAME OVER!")
            break

    print("Thanks for playing the game. Hope you enjoyed the game!")
```

This is my code so far....

Comment: You have a function called `main` but you never call it.

Comment: The best advice is to get a source debugger and step through the code figuring out where the logic goes wrong.  While some people might do this for you, you'll learn more doing it yourself and SO is not intended as a debugging service.  If you find a specific issue during debugging that you don't understand, post that problem as that would be on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the python code, it starts going from top to bottom. That is, it sets `collected_items = 0`, and then hits your `while True:` loop. It then adds 1 to collected_items, checks if collected_items is 6 and if it isn't, it goes back to the top of the loop. So it does this 6 times until `collected_items == 6` is True, and then prints and breaks out of the loop.

Once your code prints and breaks, it then gets to the `rooms ={...` line and everything else past it.

When your code eventually gets to your `def main():` line, it also only *defines* that function, it never actually runs it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have developed the game over several sessions and forgot about the first part at the top of the page. Remove the following code (or comment it out):

```
# Game loop
while True:
    # Code to play the game and collect items

    # Increment the number of collected items
    collected_items += 1

    # Check if all 6 items have been collected
    if collected_items == 6:
        # Notify the player and end the game
        print("Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the Wicked Sorcerer!")
        break
```

at the end of the file add the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I did not test the code myself. so you might still need to do other tweaks...